# Android facebook sdk 4: check if user is already logged in

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm facing a problem by using new facebook sdk. On my app, i've used old sdk, and everything works fine, but now something doesn't work well.
I have a login FragmentActivity that check if user was already logged in in the past, so open app principal activity. If user is not logged in, activity show a fragment with login options (and one option is to log in with facebook).
Fragment contains facebook login button, as described on documentation:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choose_access_type, container,
            false);
    fb_button = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fb_button);
    fb_button.setFragment(this);
    fb_button.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile",
            "user_friends"));
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    fb_button.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            //launche main activity
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code TODO
            Log.i("LOGINAFRAGMENT", "session cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code TODO
            Log.i("LOGINAFRAGMENT", "session error");
        }
    });

    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

and this is code of FragmentActivity. This activity should check if user is already connected or not:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
 AccessToken fb_token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
if(fb_token != null) {
    //already connected, launch activity
} else {
    //show fragment with login button
}
```

Now, also if user logged in the past, when I call getCurrentAccessToken I obtain always null, so fragment is showed, facebook detect that user was logged in, and main activity is launched.
How can I check directly from FragmentActivity if user was already logged in?

Comment: Try running the HelloFacebook or Scrumptious sample apps that ship with the SDK. Both of them use getCurrentAccessToken to check if the user has already logged in. You should not be getting a null unless you're clearing the token at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You can track if token changed by following:`

```
accessTokenTracker=new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
                updateWithToken(currentAccessToken);
            }
        };`
```

then use following method to update the current token:

```
     private void updateWithToken(final AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
//start next activity if user is already logged in

//                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ProfilePictureActivity.class);
                   startActivity(i);

                 finish();


        } else {
              // redirect to login activity

                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, login.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    finish();

        }
    }
}
```

call  updateWithToken(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()); after sdk initialization